# How to replicate the Angry Birds MouseOver on play button effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Most of you must have played the game Angry Birds . In it , on the start screen , we are shown the play button . On hovering over it , the button increases in size. I tried to replicate something similar and came up with [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nQKHwT0c7aerI95h5Lb)(Launch in new window). Now , my question is , which CSS-effect should I use to make it happen , since the effect I use is really bad.

My Javascript Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#play_button").hover(
            function () {
                $('#play_button').css({ "height": "240px", "width": "250px" });
            },
            function () {
                $('#play_button').css({ "height": "225px", "width": "220px" });
            }
        );
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the hover pseudo class and, possibly, transition. Sorry, can't post an answer now

Comment: @ChrisRockwell OK , thanks , but I don't understand that `pseudo-class` and `transition` :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what the Angry Birds play button looks like, but you can make a button "grow" on hover using the [hover pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wuJD9/

```
#play {
  width: 220px;
  height: 225px;
  background: tomato;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

#play:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: Hey , thanks for taking your time to post the answer , but the Angry Birds button grows in size from all the four directions , i.e. top , bottom , left , right , and not just right , and bottom.

Comment: add margin-left: -15px; margin-top: -7px; to #play:hover

Comment: @GaurangTandon or change to: `#play:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }`  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuJD9/2/).  Chris's approach is spot on - you can tweak how you like to get the results you want.

Comment: @dc5 Wow! That did it! Thanks to you and thanks to Chris to :)

Answer (score 1):

for css

```
#play_button { height:225px; width:220px;}
```

for hover

```
#play_button:hover { height:225px; width:220px;}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please .Thanks.

Comment: 1st css is to configure your button using img/background. 2nd css is to tell what css should be use when you hover the button. simple example here. http://jsfiddle.net/62hKg/

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but that doesn't replicate the effect.

Comment: have some thought on it, try this http://jsfiddle.net/wuJD9/1/
click on button to view :active effect

Comment: Doesn't work either , but I have got my answer now.Thanks for your help.